# How to import pythoncom module?. I installed py32win.exe

Tags: python, import, pycharm, pythoncom

How to import pythoncom module?. I installed py32win.exe

```
import pythoncom, pyHook, win32api, win32con
ImportError: No module named pythoncom
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

and then re-run the command.